# Rest API - Uploading large files to S3 using Pre-signed URLs and updating backend on success

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3

**Context**

I am building Stateless REST APIs for a browser-based platform that needs to store some user-generated files. These files could potentially be in the GBs.

I am using AWS S3 for storage. I have used AWS SDK in the past for this to route the file uploads through the NodeJS server (Basically - Upload to Server, Server uploads to S3).

I am trying to figure out how to improve it using the Pre-signed urls. I understand the dynamics and the flow on how to get the presigned urls and how to upload the file to S3 directly.

**I cannot use SQS or Lambda to trigger object created event.**
The architecture needs to be AWS independent.

**Question**
The simplest of flows I need to achieve is pretty common -

1. User --> Opens Profile
2. Clicks Upload Photo
3. Client Sends Request to ***/getSignedUrl***
4. Server Returns the signedURL for the file name/type
5. The client executes the PUT/POST request to upload the file to the signedUrl
6. Upload Successful

---

After this - my understanding is -

7. Client tells the server - File Uploaded Successfully
8. Server associates the S3 Url for the Photo to the User.

---

...and that's my problem. How do I associate the successfully uploaded file back to the user on the server in a secure way?

Not sure what I've been missing. It seems like a trivial use case but I haven't been able to find anything regarding it.

Answer (score -2):

1/ I think for the avatar, you should set it as public-read. 
When create signed upload url in the

```
GET: /signed-upload-url
```

You need to set the image as public-read. After that you are free to interact with image through the direct url. Since this is an avatar, so you can compress it, reduce the size of image by the AWS Lambda function.

2/ If you don't want to have the public-read, you need to associate with server to get signed-download-url to interact with image

```
GET: /signed-download-url
```

Comment: I don't even know if you read the question or not! 
1) I cannot use Lambda/SQS/SNS.
2) My Question was around connecting the successfully uploaded file to the user's account on my server.